# 12.04 call trace - system crash?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, 64-bit, system

Last night my screen suddenly turned black (black screen like when my laptop is turned off) while I was extracting a RAR file, and I was unable to restart my laptop after. Assuming it was a dead screen, I hooked my laptop to a another laptop as a spare monitor to test it but the spare screen turned black too. This morning, I tried to turn my laptop on and it loaded properly until I was asked to type in my password for my account and then this error appeared.

Does this mean that my OS crashed? This is the second time for 12.04 to crash on my laptop. First was the 32-bit, and now  64-bit. Would it be better to switch to an earlier distro like 11.10 64-bit? I'm tired to reformatting my laptop and losing files.

I am using ThinkPad R61i 12.04 64-bit 160gb hard drive 3.8gb RAM.

ETA: Roughly 6 hours after being unable to turn on my laptop, I tried to boot it again and it loaded properly to my desktop. I'm worried that this might occur again not knowing the reason for it.

[image: screenshot of error page]

Comment: Hi, I don't know the reason for your problem. But from what it looks like, it seems to be a kernel crash(panic) and not a GRUB issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for your problem. But from what it looks like, it seems to be a kernel crash(panic) and not a GRUB issue.
I haven't done any Linux kernel crash dump analysis as yet. But I did find a post that explains how to do it:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html
Hope that this helps you to find out the problem.